# GStreamer qtdemux issue when start time is set

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gstreamer, mp4

I am using GStreamer to stream videos to RTSP and have problems with many of the videos I was given. I have thousands of videos that were recorded with FFMPEG to mp4. I can't play any of the videos back as qtdemux reports the following error:

`qtdemux qtdemux.c:9129:qtdemux_parse_segments:<qtdemux0> Segment 0  extends to 4:57:00.937000000 past the end of the file duration 0:00:59.544000000 it will be truncated
qtdemux qtdemux.c:9129:qtdemux_parse_segments:<qtdemux0> Segment 1  extends to 4:58:00.481000000 past the end of the file duration 4:57:00.937000000 it will be truncated`

From what I can tell this is related to the start_pts of the video. Here is the output of ffprobe for the same video:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : libRtspServer
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:59.07, start: 5461.268000, bitrate: 2749 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2748 kb/s, 15.02 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=Main
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=29533/887000
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1920
height=1080
coded_width=1920
coded_height=1080
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuvj420p
level=41
color_range=pc
color_space=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
chroma_location=center
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=15/1
avg_frame_rate=443500/29533
time_base=1/90000
start_pts=491514120
start_time=5461.268000
duration_ts=496830060
duration=5520.334000
bit_rate=2748339
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=887
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
```

Note the start time - start_time=5461.268000

One possible solution is to remux all of the videos to have a start time of 0.00. This doesn't really seem like the ideal solution.

Is there a way to manipulate GStreamer into playing the video from time 0 instead of trying to seek to the start time? It could be possible that the videos are just not written correctly.

Comment: What is your GStreamer version?
This sounds like you have just fragments of one big mp4 - therefore each one has non zero start time?

The warning you see is that the mp4 stream length is bigger than overall mp4 file length. This is the patch that introduced the check and truncation: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-commits/2014-August/081192.html
Random ffmpeg ticket https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3859

Comment: You are correct in that this is effectively fragments of a big mp4. A video stream was decoding and written into one minute chunks.

Comment: Then the real problem is that you just need to remux the mp4 so that the video stream's time is in alignment with file overall time (not sure how this works exactly), it should be possible to do this without reencoding (so it would be quick). Maybe like this https://superuser.com/a/1358974
And you need to fix your ffmpeg recording pipeline to do the timing properly I guess.